# The model layer (MVP) should use the Activity reference

Tags: android, android-mvp

How can I make a proper separation between the Model layer and the View layer, when I have an operation in the Model that needs the current activity instance?

For example, I've integrated Linkedin SDK in my Android app (written in MVP). 
In the auth process I have the following  code snippet, when init() method's first argument type is Activity:

```
public void authWithLinkedin(final IAuth listener, Activity activity) {
    LISessionManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).init(activity, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {
            listener.onSuccess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
            listener.onError();
        }

    }, true);
}
```

If my Model layer should get to know Android framework components, what options do I have left to preserve the MVP architecture clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use software conventions / principles like

["dependency inversion principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

["ports and adapters"](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture)

Your model layer should *not* know about Android *if you can avoid it* is the point.

---

Try something like this:

Model:

```
private final SocialLoginProvider socialLoginProvider;

public MyModel(SocialLoginProvider socialLoginProvider) {
       this.socialLoginProvider = socialLoginProvider;
}

public void authWithLinkedin(final IAuth listener) {
       socialLoginProvider.init(buildScope(), new SocialLoginProvider.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {
            listener.onSuccess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError() {
            listener.onError();
        }

    }, true);
}
```

Factory:

```
public MyModel getModel(Context context) {
    LISessionManager li = LISessionManager.getInstance(context);
    SocialLoginProvider provider = new LinkedInSocialLoginProvider(context, li);
    return new MyModel(provider);
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface SocialLoginProvider {
     void init(Scope scope, Listener listener);

     interface Listener {
           void onAuthSuccess();
           void onAuthError();
     } 
}
```

Adapter for SocialLoginProvider:

```
public class LinkedInSocialLoginProvider implements SocialLoginProvider {

          private final Context context;
          private final LISessionManager linkedInSessionManager;

          public LinkedInSocialLoginProvider(Context context, LISessionManager linkedInSessionManager) {
               this.context = context;
               this.linkedInSessionManager = linkedInSessionManager;
          }

          @Override
          public void init(Scope scope, Listener listener) {
              linkedInSessionManager.init(context, scope, 
                    new AuthListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onAuthSuccess() {
                         listener.onSuccess();
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                         listener.onError();
                      }
                   }, true);
           }

}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your idea, but I still find it difficult to understand how things eventually connects to the View layer. If we try to describe the general process, I've a presenter object that holds a view and a repository (by their interfaces of course). If I understood you correctly, in my repository I need to interact with the Factory, which is the highest layer that knows about the context object existence. But in order to do that, I need to send this context from the view through the presenter, and later from the presenter through the repository. So I still have the same problem.

Comment: no `MyModel` should be composed of `LinkedInSocialLoginProvider` and your `Repository` , this is all instantiated (wired up) in the Activity `onCreate` usually so you have `Context` there. The `getModel` method I showed I was expecting you to use in an `Activity` something like `new Presenter(view, model);`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it is ok to have Android Framework components in the Model layer. For example you will need the `Context` to store/access data locally using `getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)` and/or to manage local DB using `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

The `LISessionManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).init` seems to be like a `BroadcastReceiver` as it is a type of listener that receives a particular result from an outside component. To handle such a case you can refer to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/5gdlrl/mvp_and_servicesbroadcastreceiversetc/dat52t9/)